# redirect_uri_mismatch from Google Analytics Embed API only when page is hosted non-locally

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

When I host the sample javascript Google Analytics Embed API code [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started#copy-and-paste) on *localhost*, everything works fine as long as I add localhost to the authorized javascript origins list in the Google developers console. This works even with nothing specified in the "Authorized redirect URIs" list.

When I host the page on a real (i.e. non-localhost) site, and add the new authorized javascript origin, I get the **400 redirect_uri_mismatch** error. The details of the error show the following as the redirect_uri:

storagerelay://http/analytics.mysite.com?id=authxxxxxx

To try to solve this problem, I've added the following URIs to the "Authorized redirect URIs" list of my OAuth2 credentials:

- xxxx://analytics.mysite.com/oauth2callback
- xxxx://analytics.mysite.com

(where xxxx = http to work around stack overflow not letting me post more than 2 links)

The error persists. None of the other questions or answers posted here on SO have helped.

So my questions are:

1. How do I get this to authorize when not hosted locally?
2. For my javascript web application, do I need to create any folder or
   file called oauth2callback? If so, what needs to be in that folder
   or file? (I've only seen this addressed on SO for PHP, which appears
   to be quite a bit different in how authentication is achieved.)
3. Why is the redirect_uri given in the error so odd looking? How can I match it in the "Authorized redirect URIs" list? (It gives a formatting error if I copy/paste it exactly.)

Comment: where are you hosting it?

Comment: @DaImTo It is hosted at analytics.thewindlog.com